# How to output any JSON sent to endpoint?

Tags: vapor

One of my Vapor app endpoints needs to be able to receive arbitrary JSON and output it to the logs. Once I have the logs, I can go back through and set up Codables structs and do the typical Vapor workflow.

Answer (score 2):

In your route handler do `print("\(req)")` and you'll see the data

Comment: Shockingly easily!

Answer (score 0):

Doing this requires solving two problems that Vapor apps don't normally contend with:

1. Where to get the HTTP body (and how to decode it)?
2. How to return a future outside the context of the usual helpers?

The simplest solution I found gets the body from `req.http.body.data`, converts the data to JSON using `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:options)`, and returns a Future using `req.eventLoop.newSucceededFuture`:

```swift
router.put("printanyjson") { req -> Future<HTTPStatus> in
    if let data = req.http.body.data {
        if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) {
            print("\(json)")
        }
    }
    return req.eventLoop.newSucceededFuture(result: .ok)
}
```

Note #1: This solution [does not work if body is streaming](http://api.vapor.codes/http/3.1.0/HTTP/Structs/HTTPBody.html#/s:4HTTP8HTTPBodyV4data10Foundation4DataVSgvp). I'd like to see a solution that incorporates this idea.

Note #2: It's also possible to make recursive Codables that can decode any structure, allowing you to stay within the rails of typical Vapor usage. I'd like to see a solution that incorporates this idea.